# How to set tab order by a macro in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, tab-ordering

I have a MS Word form with ActiveX control (not the form control). Suppose I have two textboxes and two option button as follows:

```
Name: [textBox1]
Address: [textBox2]
Gender: [opt1] Male [opt2] Female
```

Now if I want a tab order, I have to add following macro:

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 9 Then
textBox2.Activate
End If
End Sub

Private Sub textBox2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 9 Then
opt1.Activate
End If
End Sub

Private Sub opt1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 9 Then
opt2.Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Now in my real form there are 20 text boxes and 12 option buttons, so it is quite boring to write down keydown event for each form field. How can I write a macro so that it will first get the name of current form field on keydown (and validating it as tab keydown) and then go to next form field?

For the sake of tab order, I will then rename all form field chronologically such as field1, field2, field3......... etc, so that with an increment the code can move the tab to next form field.

Here is the screen shot of ActiveX tools those I used in forms:

[image]

I have [cross-posted this topic](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?63007-How-to-set-tab-order-by-a-macro-in-ms-word&p=381290#post381290) to VbaExpress forum also.

Comment: MS Forms controls are ActiveX controls. Besides being available in UserForms, they can also be placed on the document surface. I'm assuming you mean these, since the screen shot you showed in a different post was for such a control. But before we start thinking about it, please confirm that you're using these controls and not ones you've added to the Toolbox. And you've placed these on teh document surface? Inline with the text or with text wrap formatting?

Comment: Please note also that *form fields* in Word are something very specific and that is NOT ActiveX controls. Using the term "form field" in your question is extremely misleading.

Comment: Hello Cindy Meister, I can assure you that I have used ActiveX controls. Procedure was: Open a new ms word file(A4 Portrait)>Developer Tab>Design Mode>ActiveX Controls>Placed on the page. I didn't use labels for Controls such as text box, instead I used plain text as in normal document of ms word. I have updated my topic with screenshot of tools (ActiveX) that I used in forms.

Comment: Yes, these are the same controls as used in MS Forms (press Alt+F9 to toggle the underlying field code and you'll see they belong to the class `Forms`), and these are *not* form fields - form fields are the "Legacy Forms" listing. So, no text wrap formatting...

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to be any happier with this answer than you were with my last...

The problem is that the keypress, or KeyDown, is only triggered by the fact that the focus is *in* an ActiveX control, and will be specific to that control. So you have no choice than a KeyDown event for every control. You can keep the code in the event to a minimum, but...

There's no way to identify controls on a document surface directly by name as a *string*. `ThisDocument.ControlName` is possible, but there's nothing like ThisDocument.Controls("ControlName") available that would let you substitute names, nor allow you to identify the name of the current control.

There is a way to do it, but it's convoluted. Since these are in-line with the text (no text wrapping) they belong to the document's `InlineShapes` collection. Their programming interface can only be addressed through the InlineShape's `OLEFormat.Object` property. This means the code needs to loop the InlineShapes collection *twice*: once to identify the ActiveX control where the key was pressed, once to identify the control which should be next.

The following code illustrates the principle. What it does *not* do is

- work for more than 9 controls - that would require code that checks, from the right of the name, how many characters are numerical
- go back to the first control if focus is in the last

Note that it *might* be possible to get around event code for each control. It would involve using the Windows API, which means it would fire *every time* the user presses Tab. But I have no idea whether the key presses would be captured when focus is inside a control. And you would have to test each time if this is the case - and you'd still have to be able to identify which control the focus is in.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    GoToNextControl KeyCode, ThisDocument.TextBox1.Name
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    GoToNextControl KeyCode, ThisDocument.TextBox2.Name
End Sub

Sub GoToNextControl(KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, controlName As String)
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape, ils2 As Word.InlineShape
    Dim c As MSForms.Control
    Dim baseName As String, nextName
    Dim nameCounter As Long
    baseName = Mid(controlName, 1, Len(controlName) - 1)
    nameCounter = Right(controlName, 1)

    If KeyCode = 9 Then
        For Each ils In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
            If ils.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                If ils.OLEFormat.Object.Name = controlName Then
                    nextName = baseName & nameCounter + 1
                    For Each ils2 In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
                       If ils2.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
                           If ils2.OLEFormat.Object.Name = nextName Then
                                ils2.Select
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

All-in-all it might make more sense to stick to the legacy form fields or to content controls, or move this to a UserForm that then writes to the document.

Comment: Thanks for your hardwork and code. very much disappointed to know that there is no simple workaround. I don't like form control as it's text box is flat, doesn't look like traditional text box. Anyway, I am giving you Upvote for your hard work and try. Thanks again.